# Fastest way to delete matching rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, delete

I have more than **10 million** records in a table. I want to delete the
records where the email column contains `.ac.`.

What is the fastest method to perform the task?

**Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `master` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Delete Query**

```
DELETE FROM `master` WHERE ( email LIKE "%.ac.%" );
```

Comment: show create table table_name; ?

Comment: @MichaelGardner : the question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not given much of a table description. Notwithstanding, I will try to answer your question.

For this example, let's use this table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

First, try counting all the IDs that have `.ac.` in the email column.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @CompleteCount FROM mytable;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @DeleteCount FROM mytable WHERE LOCATE('.ac.',email) > 0;
```

There are two approaches to doing a DELETE:

## APPROACH #1 : DELETE JOIN

If @DeleteCount < 5% of @CompleteCount, use a list of IDs to DELETE from `mytable`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_delete_id
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE LOCATE('.ac.',email) > 0;
ALTER TABLE mytable_delete_id ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
DELETE B.* FROM mytable_delete_id A INNER JOIN mytable B USING (id);
DROP TABLE mytable_delete_id;
```

This helps take the guess work out of which rows to DELETE by using a SELECT to get the IDs. The JOIN takes care of the DELETE.

## APPROACH #2 : CREATE A NEW TABLE

If you have the following conditions:

- @DeleteCount > 30% of @CompleteCount
- your table does not have foreign keys/constraints

you could  just create a new table and filter out the rows with `.ac.` in the email column:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_new LIKE mytable;
#insert rows which does not contain '.ac.' from mytable
INSERT INTO mytable_new SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOCATE('.ac.',email) = 0;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME mytable_old;
ALTER TABLE mytable_new RENAME mytable;
DROP TABLE mytable_old;
```

## EPILOGUE

You can do either of these methods without checking table counta ahead of time. They will both work. If you are concerned that `.ac.` is in a huge number of rows, go with APPROACH #2. If there are not that many occurrences, go with APPROACH #1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the simple method, i.e:

```
delete col_name from table table name where like condition ;
```

I'm not sure about MySQL, but most probably it works in Oracle.

Comment: You need not the `col_name` in `DELETE` statements.